# Elastalert simplified multiple rules in one file

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert, elastic-beats

I'm writing `Elastalart` rules for heartbeat i.e if service or machine are/is down, I should get notified. Right now I can create one rule for service per one file like below.

```
name: My Alert
type: frequency
index: heartbeat-*
num_events: 5
timeframe:
    minutes: 2

filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "url.domain: MY_LOCALHOST01.local AND monitor.status: down"

alert:
- "email"

email:
- "user@example.in"
```

Is there any way, can I specify multiple rules??... I can specify multiple filter like below

```
...
filter:
- query: # Filter 1
    query_string:
      query: "url.domain: MY_LOCALHOST01.local AND monitor.status: down"

- query: # Filter 2
    query_string:
      query: "url.domain: MY_LOCALHOST02.local AND monitor.status: down"
...
```

But Elatalert consider `num_events` on ALL filters. For example, I dont want to get alert for situation like `Filter 1` got 3 hits and `Filter 2` got 2 hits i.e 3+2=5 which is equal to `num_events`.

So, is there any ways the `num_events` should check per filter? like if `Filter 1` got 5 hits and `Filter 2` got 3 hits, then I can confirm `MY_LOCALHOST01` is really DOWN and send alert.

I don't want multiple files. It would be hard to manage/modify.

Comment: Is that ok for you to handle this with the help of separate index? I suspect a way if its OK.

Comment: I didn't get that. What do you mean separate index?

Comment: An index to handle the rules logic and check whether enough events occurred to trigger alert.

Comment: Yes, sure. Please suggest :-)

Comment: Are your `filters` based on same set of fields? `domain and status`?

Comment: Yes, those belongs to same dataset

Comment: Yes both `"url.domain: MY_LOCALHOST01.local AND monitor.status: down"` are in same `document`

Comment: `Filter1`, `Filter2` works on same set of field `url.domain, monitor.status`. And how many such filters you have. Or do you have filters works on different column combined together in the same rule file?

Comment: I have around 10 filters. Filter1, Filter2 works on same set of fields

Comment: What about other filters? I thought of using `change type` with an `index` if they are all on same set of fields.

Comment: other filter are also same, just a change of `url.domain` i.e `MY_LOCALHOST03.local`, `MY_LOCALHOST04.local`, `MY_LOCALHOST05.local`, etc

Comment: Did you get a chance to try that?

Comment: No, I will try today manybe :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to think before doing this.

To achieve the expected result:

1. Have `rule_type` as [change](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#rule-types) instead `frequency`
2. Keep the same timeframe.
3. Monitor on `status` as you want to check whether it is `down`
4. Set filter on `monitor` field.
5. Set `alert` as [POST](https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#http-post)
6. You can have your own backend API to which you can redirect - You can send the entire document which got changed - Through which you can identify which `domain` is down. Backend API can write to an index which domain is down. Key name is `domain_name`. You can keep a counter kind of thing to increase. I am not sure whether we can directly post too ES. But documentation says any end point which accepts JSON.
7. Now you have your `frequency`rule set on the new index. Have your filters as `OR` - `domain1_down : 5 OR domain2_down:5`. You can have your same `email` alerting. But you need to derive which domain from the `key` or you can have one more field in the index to be used by alerting.

Here the trickiest point is that `your config says you want to find 5 downtimes of a domain in 2 minutes of timeframe`

By using the aforementioned steps, you can find whether it went down 5 times. But not within 2 minutes time frame. I guess that you can achieve that by keeping a field `previous_down_time` in the extra index.

It's harder way to achieve what is needed. I don't think there is no other better way than maintaining separate files. That is not harder than this.

Comment: I cant accept the answer untill I test it. But I gave you the bounty for your workaround

Comment: Please try and let me know.

Comment: I think, there is similar question in github issue. https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/2849 Do you think, is that related to this

Comment: I think it is related to this - https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ruletypes.html#query-key