# Is it possible to find if. a single attribute is modified in an Elasticsearch document

Tags: java, http, elasticsearch

Is it possible to find if. a single attribute is modified in an Elasticsearch document, does Elasticsearch provide me a callback which I can listen to somehow using an internal or an external tool or library. I would like to trigger an action of re-populating another attribute in the same document by making an HTTP call which could be time consuming as well and hence would want to do this in an asynchronous fashion

Any suggestions are really appreciated

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51980618/4604579

Comment: How about using `elastlalert`'s `change` type. This might [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62431835/elastalert-simplified-multiple-rules-in-one-file/62609212#62609212) - not a straight forward answer, but answer provides suggestion about `change` event.

Answer (score 4):

As linked in my comment above, there is no such features in Elasticsearch yet, even though the [Changes API](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/1242) should provide exactly what you need, but it is still in the works, and there's no known release date yet.

In the meantime, you might be lucky with [ForgeRock's Changes Feed Plugin](https://github.com/ForgeRock/es-change-feed-plugin), even though it has a [few shortcomings](https://github.com/ForgeRock/es-change-feed-plugin#limitations) such as the one I've commented about [here](https://github.com/ForgeRock/es-change-feed-plugin/issues/17).

But if you don't have too many nodes and your index doesn't have too many shards, it might work out well for you. According to my tests, you get a constant feed of changes as soon as a document changes.